Part of a mapping is a text object and I wish to pass it to a function. How to do that?
I wish to have a mapping like the one included in the following code:
var a = 'foo'
var b = 'bar'
xnoremap s<text_object> <ScriptCmd>Myfunction(a, b, <text_object>)

If for example I hit siw, then I wish that Myfunction is called with Myfunction(a, b, 'iw').

I'm not sure it possible as such but If you tell us more about your use case maybe some of us can propose an alternative way to help you.

Thanks @VivianDeSmedt. I think :h map-operator  - and everything connected - is a good place where to start to look at.

To write your own operator, see :help map-operator and in particular the g@ operator and operatorfunc option.
See also the Learn Vimscript the Hard Way chapters on custom operators.
